# EasyEclipse for Ruby and Rails doesn't start because of an application error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eclipse, installation

I have just installed [EasyEclipse for Ruby and Rails](http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/distributions/ruby-rails.html). When trying to start it I get the following error message:

> An error has occurred. See the log file [path to log file]

The content of the [log file](http://txtup.co/v7Jgm) is roughly as follows:

```
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3236 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    [22 more lines of the form "at java.lang..." or "at org.eclipse..."]

!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved 
because the following root constraints are not resolved:
[about lines specifying missing bundles such as "com.aptana.ide.parsing_0.0.0"]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: you seem to be missing the platform-specific bindings for SWT (the UI framework) are you sure to have downloaded the version for 32 bit Windows? Eclipse has specially packaged versions for each OS. Perhaps EasyEclispe does not have a 32 bit version?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, set eclipse.exe to "run as administrator".

1. Browse to the EasyEclipse install directory (default: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyEclipse for Ruby and Rails x.x.x.x)
2. Right-click eclipse.exe and go to properties
3. On the compatibility tab, enable "Run this program as an administrator" then click ok